# Adjoint orbits of a finite group of type $G_2$

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, lie-algebras, exceptional-groups

Let $q=p^\alpha$ be a prime power and $k=\mathbb{F}_q$. Let $G\subseteq \mathrm{GL}_N(k)$ be a simple finite group of Lie type, with root system of type $G_2$, and let $\mathfrak{g}\subseteq \mathfrak{gl}_N(k)$ be (the $k$-points of) its Lie-algebra.

Is anybody aware of an accessible reference where I could find a classification of the orbits for the adjoint action of $G$ on $\mathfrak{g}$, including orbit sizes?

Other exceptional groups over $k$ are also of interest to me, so if such a reference for them also exists I'd be happy to hear about it.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you looking for more than the (known, I think?) reduction to nilpotent orbits, and description of the latter in e.g. Humphreys ([1995](http://ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1343976), cf. pp. 138, 158)?

Comment: I think this should be enough, i`ll have a look at Humphreys. Thanks!

Comment: From memory, Carter's *Finite groups of Lie type* also has this -- see the tables in the back. (And don't confuse this book with his other book with title *Simple groups of Lie type*.)

Answer (score 0):

There is an accessible list of rational orbits (including also non-semisimple-non-nilpotent ones) in this paper: [Jackson - The rational adjoint orbits of a Lie algebra of type G2](https://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/ResearchReports/Algebra/Jac/1998-19.html).